# Visual Studio solution explorer out of memory exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I open the visual studio 2010 premium, Solution explorer doesn't show up.
It was working and now its not.

It is showing a out of memory exception. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Attached is the screen shot[image]

Comment: How much memory do you have in your system?

Comment: And - How large is your solution?

Comment: Does this happen when you just opened visual studio or when you tried to open a solution? Please give more info.

Comment: Lemme check my ouiji.... you have 1gb of memory on your machine.

Comment: I have 3.5 gb of memory with Intel i5 650 processor.

Comment: It happens for all the solutions and project.

Comment: When I try to reset settings using import and export settings wizard. I get this error Unable to import property 'TrackFileSelectionInExplorer' because it contains invalid data '0'.

Comment: Increasing the virtual memory did the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try resetting visual studio by closing it out completely and running the following command.

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

Comment: what happens when you create a new solution from scratch with nothing in it?  Does it work?  If so then add a project and see if it works.  If not then come back and share what happened.

Comment: Same error shows up when I add new solution or project from scratch. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but the error doesn't go.

Comment: you should run devenv /log and it will output to H:\settings\application data\microsoft\visualstudio\10.0\ActivityLog.xml so you can see what's happening in that log file.  If it doesn't tell you enough for you to fix it then post back the log file.  OR - contact microsoft support.

Comment: It works. The problem was with the virtual memory. After increasing the virtual memory it works. Thanks.

Comment: @bunny - You are running low on virtual memory with 3.5 jigawatts of RAM?  Have you been messing with your paging file settings?

Comment: i've got the same problem since a few days at home and also at my job. I don't know if it could be a plugin update that could create this problem of OutOfMemoryException. One sure thing is that the problem is not coming from the computer, it must be somewhere in the updates from the last days.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend submitting this to https://connect.microsoft.com as a bug.

They will most likely ask for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This exception can have more than one cause.  It isn't very likely that Visual Studio is actually running out of memory, the system might be running low on resources.  The desktop heap is one of them.  A simple reboot will fix that.

If this reoccurs, use Taskmgr.exe to try to find the processes that are hogging resources.  View + Select Columns, tick Handles, USER objects and GDI objects.  If it is Explorer then you have a misbehaving shell extension handler.