# VS 2010, Solution Explorer not showing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer

OK recently I uninstall NuGet Packages because I had to install MVC 3 and I already had MVC 4 installed and for some reason it gave me an error with the NuGet version when trying to install MVC 3. So after uninstalling NuGet I proceed to install MVC 3 and it went Ok. But for some reason my **Solution Explorer View stop working**.

If I open a new Visual Studio instances and open any project the solution explorer is not visible, if I try to open it via View -> Solution Explorer nothing happens. When I run the project the Solution Explorer view appears but with an error. This error:

[image]

I don't know how to run with the /log parameter.

*What's going on with my solution explorer view?*

**Edit 1**: Has `@Rocky` suggested I run with `/log` and the `ActivityLog.xml` have the following structure:

```
<entry>
    <record>304</record>
    <time>2014/10/14 19:19:29.988</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PERF: Shell start. 43011 ms</description>
</entry>
```

Comment: start->run (or win+r) and write devenv /log
and check how much memory is available in task manager (ctrl+shift+esc). did you try rebooting?

Comment: @rocky devenv is using 55.368 KB without any project opened. Yes I did try rebooting VS and also the PC and nothing.

Comment: What is logged to ActivityLog.xml when you launch devenv with the /log parameter?

Comment: @rocky 308 entries. I edited my question with the structured.

Comment: Try running devenv /resetsettings (make sure you close all VS instances first)

Comment: You can also try increasing virtual memory of your system - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7

Comment: You can also try repairing visual studio

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio solution explorer out of memory exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727835/visual-studio-solution-explorer-out-of-memory-exception)

Comment: @rocky ok I'm gonna try increasing virtual memory, but how much you recommend me to assign?

Comment: i have 32gb...depends on how much space do you have on your drive ;)