# Visual Studio Running out of Memory while using 2 gb out of 16

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have no clue why I am getting an out of memory error prompt even though VS is only using 1.2 - 2 gb and still have over 50% of memory left with background programs running, I am coding in VB.net if that means anything.

Comment: Visual Studio is a 32-bit program so it only gets to use up to 2 GB, although normally that is plenty. [Visual Studio solution explorer out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4728465/1115360) might help.

Comment: Maybe try an updated version. I had a memory issue with VS 2015 and after adding a patch it used less memory.